# Is that possible to get an array of information inside a $_POST["array"]{input1},{input...}

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to do something like that

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    if (isset($_POST["array"])) //Reset Button
    {
        print_r($_POST["array"]); //Able to print all the "whatever"Value below
    }
}
```

from an html code like that

```
<form name="array" method="post" action="W3schoolTest.php">
     <?php
            foreach ($columnsList as $column) {
                echo $column.' : ';
                echo '<input type="text" name="'.$whateverItShouldBeFind.'"><br />'; 
            }
            echo '<br /><input type="submit"/>';
     ?>
</form>
```

I know that I can register my whateverValue name in a `$_SESSION` but i was looking for a proper way.

Thanks !

Comment: You need to clarify your question, this doesn't make any sense:
"I'm looking for a way able to put many do something like that"

Comment: Oh yes sorry....

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Something like what?

Comment: I do not understand the question but `$_POST["array"]` will be undefined, since the form has no inputs with `name="array"`   eg; $_POST is populated with `input` names, not form names

Comment: I want to get an array of Input by using only one keyWord inside my $_POST

Comment: *but i was looking for a proper way* This seems to be looking for a best practice which is not really a question SO is used for they generally create answer that are based on opinion.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying ! Its over !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible with the following notation:

**For POST:**

```
<input type="text" name="array[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" value="some-text" />
```

And on the server:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

should produce something like the following:

```
array(1) {
  'array' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] => int(1)
    [1] => int(2)
    [2] => string(9) "some-text"
  }
}
```

**For GET:**
The URL should look like the following:

http://example.com?array[]=1&array[]=2&array[]=some-text

Comment: if (!empty($_POST["array"])) // not array[] directly